# Learning to use ATmel Studio - using BOSSA downloader

Tags: atmel-studio

The basic question - is BOSSA the right SOFTWARE  "tool" to use in ATmel Studio to **connect / download to Arduino DUE AND NOT using VisualMicro**?

I cannot get BOSSA to AUtoScan for COM port.
Getting error "Could not find a device" 
When I select my COM port ( COM4 ) which works in Arduino IDE
I get "Could not connect to device on COM4"

This tells me that ATmel Studio does not recognize my Due at all.

Could someone please advise me what did I missed in configuring the Studio?

I can use Studio to run Arduino IDE (VisualMicro ) but I need to get away from Arduino IDE environment.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Per doc SAM3X8E has build-in downloader( NO need for BOSSA?) , so I have installed SAM-BA but having trouble installing CDC driver for XP

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Due needs a patched version of Bossa, not the 1.2.1 version available on SourceForge. Supposedly the patched version is available on GitHub, or you can copy the version in the Arduino IDE.

Also, the Due USB port must be put into bootloader mode. Open then close the serial port at 1200 baud, and it will re-instantiate as a Bossa programming port.

To return to serial port mode, the only way I have found is to power cycle the Due.